# Erro ao executar spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Field authenticationManager in com.ronaldo.money.api.config.AuthorizationServerConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.
> ```

Action:

> ```
> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.
> ```

Minha classe:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("teste")
            .secret("teste")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom dia, 
 Consegui resolver da seguinte forma, talvez funcione em seu cenário também.

Primeiro criei uma classe estendendo WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class CustomSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

E meu AuthorizationServerConfig ficou assim

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("client")
            .secret("encrypt secret")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(20)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600 * 24);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

    endpoints
        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
        .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("singningKeyP");
    return accessTokenConverter;
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ele não está encontrando o bean para injetar, possivelmente porque não foi criado em lugar nenhum. Tente criar o bean no fim da classe:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
  return authenticationManager();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mesmo colocando o método com o Bean, não funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Bom tarde, para resolve essa questao com spring 2, fiz assim.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("angular").secret(passwordEncoder().encode("@ngul@r0")).scopes("read", "write")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").accessTokenValiditySeconds(300)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600 * 12); na sua implemetação so tira o refresh_token    
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).reuseRefreshTokens(false);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("secret");
        return accessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterCustom extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder.encode("admin")).roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/categorias").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/categorias");
    }

}
```

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        additionalInfo.put("organization", " Token Custom ");
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentar usar o `Qualifier`

```
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```